# Is there some way to replace Doctrine in Symfony with some REST client?

Tags: java, rest, symfony, doctrine-orm

I would like to rewrite Symfony project to JAVA, but we would like to start building REST services first, and somehow replace model with them. Some time it should work together with the Doctrine model. Later we would replace the core as well. The idea is, to keep project live, being able to add new features in JAVA, but keep the old features working as well.
Is there someone who already did something like that?
How would you proceed in such case?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is very possible. Your reasons for migration aside, I would advise you to look at [Facebook's GraphQL](https://github.com/facebook/graphql). It's a query language and execution engine tied to any backend service. There is already a bundle for this here https://github.com/Youshido/GraphQLBundle.

Expose your doctrine queries and persistence via GraphQL and changing it from Doctrine to raw PHP, or from Symfony to Django or Java, or back to Symfony and whatever client consumes your API wont know a thing and thus will never break.